# Adding 1 bit flag to the 802.11n mac frame header

Tags: header, frame, flags, wifi

For my work i need to add 1 bit flag to 802.11n mac frame header..

I'm a little bit confused about this flag .. do i have to add it to the mac header "is there any place for a 1 bit flag" or it's something related to ampdu ?

```
struct DOT11_FrameHdr{
                                //  Should Be  Actually
UInt8             frameType;    //      -         -
UInt8             frameFlags;   //      2         2
UInt16            duration;     //      2         2
Mac802Address     destAddr;     //      6         6
Mac802Address     sourceAddr;   //      6         6
Mac802Address     address3;     //      6         6
UInt16            fragId: 4,    //      -         -
                  seqNo: 12 ;   //      2         2
char              FCS[4];       //      4         4
                                //---------------------
                                //     28        28
```

};

Any help ?

Comment: How could we know where you want to add a 1 bit flag ? You'll need to explain this a bit more.

Comment: @nos at the head of the transmission queue before assigning the retry limits for this frame.

Comment: And are you programming in a specific environment/operating system, where you have access to this transmission queue ? Are you using a specific API that is relevant here ?

Comment: @nos I'm using Qualnet struct DOT11_FrameHdr{
                                    
    UInt8             frameType;    
    UInt8             frameFlags;   //      2         2
    UInt16            duration;   
    Mac802Address     destAddr;    
    Mac802Address     sourceAddr;  
    Mac802Address     address3; 
    UInt16            fragId: 4,    //      -         -
                      seqNo: 12 ;  
    char              FCS[4];     
                                    //---------------------
                                    //     28        28
};

Comment: @nos you can see the question again if you please,, i did edit it